# How do you conditionally check for an escape character?

Tags: python, escaping, conditional-statements, literals, string-literals

I have a string which contains the escape character `\x` . However if i try to check for it with:

```
if char == "\x":
```

I receive the error

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

Comment: `\xhh` is *syntax*, not an actual value. A *string representation* (return value of `repr()` represents any character outside the *printable* ASCII range with such sequences, did you want to see if there are any such characters? Can you give us a sample?

Comment: @MartijnPieters a string is returned using repr() and that is what I am searching within. It returns it in the \xhh syntax and my goal is to concatenate the hh values to form what was initially meant to be saved as 32 bit values within the files. So my code currently concatenates 4 sequences of hh characters, checking for \x and breaking there, to form a 4 byte value

Comment: @JohnSmith - the typical tool for reconstructing binary objects from a string of bytes is [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > I have a string which contains the escape character `\x`

No you don't. There is no such things as "the escape character `\x`". `\x` is two characters, not one. The first character is the backslash, the second character is lower-case x.

You have to escape the backslash in order to defeat its meaning.

```
if two_character_string == "\\x":
```

or perhaps

```
if first_char == "\\" and second_char == "x":
```